# Как решить задачу на бин поиск?

Tags: c++, олимпиада, бинарный-поиск

Не понимаю почему, 2 день не могу решить задачу. Ломается на одном тесте(WA).

> Меньше либо равно В этой задаче вам нужно будет несколько раз находить
> в отсортированном массиве первое число, которое меньше либо равно
> числу из запроса. Обратите внимание - в этой задаче массив нумеруется
> с единицы. Входные данные В  первой строке записаны два целых числа
> n, m (1≤n,m≤2 * 10^5) - размер массива и количество
> запросов. Во второй строке записаны n целых чисел в невозрастающем
> порядке, каждое по модулю не превышает 1 * 10^9. Эти числа образуют
> данный массив. В следующих mm строках даны числа запросов, по одному в
> строке. Выходные данные Для каждого запроса выведите индекс самого
> левого числа в массиве, которое меньше либо равно данному. Если такого
> числа нет, вместо него выведите NO SOLUTION

```
Sample Input: 
10 10 
16 15 13 5 3 -1 -4 -6 -15 -18
-1 7 -6 0 5 18 15 3 -18 -19 
Sample Output: 
6 4 8 6 4 1 2 5 10 NO SOLUTION
```

Мой код -

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long binary(long array[], long x, long n){
    if (x > array[0]) return 1;

    long l = -1;
    long r = n;

    while (l < r){
        long mid = l + (r - l) / 2;

        if (x < array[mid]){
            l = mid + 1;
        }
        else{
            r = mid;
        }

    }

    return l + 1;

}

int main()
{
    long n, m, x;

    cin >> n >> m;
    long array[n];

    for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> array[i];
    for (long j = 0; j < m; j++){
        cin >> x;
        if (x < array[n - 1])
            cout << "NO SOLUTION" << endl;

        else
            cout << binary(array, x, n) << endl;


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Очень помогает, если вы даете URL системы. Судите сами — так можно сразу проверять, правильная ли идея. А иначе надо давать вам ответ, через несколько часов услышать "не работает" и придумывать что-то еще? И зачем это надо? :)

Comment: Да, не подумал). Вот здесь проверяется задание - https://stepik.org/lesson/307318/step/9?unit=289406

Comment: А так: `long l =  0; ... return l;` ?

Comment: Намекаю: попробуйте на данных `1 3 3 4 3 2`. По логике должно дать `1 1 NO SOLUTION`. А что дает?

Comment: как и должно 1 1 NO SOLUTION

Comment: @Mbo Спасибо большое!!!! Ваш совет помог!!!

Comment: Я имею в виду исправления в процедуре бинарного поиска. Второе не нужно, я забыл, что у вас с единицы ответ считается, только инициализацию l сделать нулём

Comment: Дает `1 0 NO SOLUTION`. По крайней мере в VC++ 2022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сверив процедуру бинарного поиска с `binary_search_leftmost` [здесь](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Binary_search_algorithm&action=edit&section=5), видим, что `l` должно инициализироваться нулём.

```
  long l = 0;
    long r = n;

    while (l < r){
        long mid = l + (r - l) / 2;

        if (x < array[mid]){
            l = mid + 1;
        }
        else{
            r = mid;
        }

    }

    return l + 1;

}
```